# Ошибка TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Выдает все ссылки сайта, как сделать так, чтобы выдавалась первая?

```
link = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'item-title text-short'})
for div in link:
    print(div.find('a')['href'])
```

Ошибка

```
print(div.find('a')['href'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `div.find('a')` вернул `None`, т.к. тег `a` не был найден, соответственно, `None['href']` и вызвал ошибку в вопросе.

Могу предложить проверку:

```
for div in link:
    a = div.find('a')
    if a:
        print(a['href'])
```

Или альтернативную проверку:

```
for div in link:
    a = div.find('a')
    if not a:
        continue

    print(a['href'])
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы выдавалась только первая ссылка?

Comment: Есть разные способы, например после `print(a['href'])` написать `break` и цикл досрочно закончится

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Тогда, отметьте ответ как правильный, чтобы не висел вопрос без ответа

Answer (score 3):

Для сложного поиска я бы лучше css селекторы использовал

```
soup.select('div.item-title.text-short a')
```

Данный запрос вернет список всех элементов a, которые находятся внутри тега div с классами item-title и text-short. Далее просто берем первый элемент - это и будет первая ссылка.

А еще лучше не искать нужный элемент по номеру, а задать точное условие по классу или id. Это не сильно усложнит css селекор, зато такой запрос будет более устойчив к изменениям страницы